# Finding Max and Min coordinates for X and Y in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, max, min

Working with a dictionary of the form {name: (x, y)}, I need to return the maximum and minimum of both the x and y coordinates, so 4 values in total.

The code I'm attempting to use is a solution to a similar question I found and tried to adapt (it seems to work for the X value, but not the Y):

```
maxY = particleCoords[max(particleCoords.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(0))[0]][1]
minY = particleCoords[min(particleCoords.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(0))[0]][1]
```

(the name of the dictionary is particleCoords)

The numbers are floats, and can be negative.

I know there are a lot of similar questions to this, but the one I did find that seemed to be the same thing I couldn't adapt.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems to me like:

```
min_x = min(particleCoords.iteritems(),key = lambda item: item[1][0])
max_x = max(particleCoords.iteritems(),key = lambda item: item[1][0])

min_y = min(particleCoords.iteritems(),key = lambda item: item[1][1])
max_y = max(particleCoords.iteritems(),key = lambda item: item[1][1])
```

should work...

The comparison of each item is based on the *value* (`item[1]`) portion of each item.  Then depending on whether we want `x` or `y` we either compare the first or second element in the *value*.

This will give you the key-value pair which is minimal/maximal depending on the particular key function.  If you don't care about getting the names, you can do this a little more cleanly:

```
min_x = min(particleCoords.itervalues(),key = itemgetter(0))
max_x = max(particleCoords.itervalues(),key = itemgetter(0))

min_y = min(particleCoords.itervalues(),key = itemgetter(1))
max_y = max(particleCoords.itervalues(),key = itemgetter(1))
```

Again the `min_x` and `max_x` are actually the `(x,y)` pair which hold the minimal and maximal `x` respectively.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution using zip and list comprehension as long as you don't need to map the value to the keys. However, I'm not sure whether it would be faster or slower than the previously mentioned methods.

```
(x_max, x_min),  (y_max, y_min) = [(max(x), min(x)) for x in zip(*my_dict.values())]
```

Comment: You're about 3 years too late, but I appreciate the advice. ;)

Comment: Yes I know :-). Full disclosure: I'm a new-ish contributor here and part of the reason I answered was simply so that I could finally get past 15 points here on SE so I can actually upvote the excellent answers on here that help me so much. So finally I had a problem that I solved on my own and then wondered if somebody else had had this issue so I figured I'd contribute to the general body of knowledge :-)

Comment: Aha, fair enough! No harm in adding to older questions.

Comment: This is just stunningly beautiful code.  I'm glad you posted it!

Answer (score 1):

This would also work:

```
>>> d = {'name1': (1, 6), 'name2': (7, 4), 'name3': (10, 1)}
>>> v = d.values()
>>> zipped = zip(*v)
>>> print min(zipped[0]), max(zipped[0]), min(zipped[1]), max(zipped[1])
1 10 1 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I interpret your question correctly but if you want to get the extreme values from all tuples in a dictionary/associative array of tuples of the form `{<key>: (x, y)}`, then this might give you what you need:

```
my_dict = {
           "bananas": (3, 5),
           "apples": (2, 5),
           "oranges": (4, 7)
           }

x_min = None
x_max = None
y_min = None
y_max = None

for x in my_dict:
    try:
        if my_dict[x][0] < x_min: x_min = my_dict[x][0]
        elif my_dict[x][0] > x_min: x_max = my_dict[x][0]
        if my_dict[x][1] < y_min: y_min = my_dict[x][1]
        elif my_dict[x][1] > y_max: y_max = my_dict[x][1]
    except:
        x_min = my_dict[x][0]
        x_max = my_dict[x][0]
        y_min = my_dict[x][1]
        y_max = my_dict[x][1]

print("Extremes (min, max) for position (x, y) are: ((%s, %s), (%s, %s))" \
      % (x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max))
```

Is that what you were after?